# Django - use middleware to block debug data on some cases

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django in debug mode in dev environment.

When some views fail, it returns the debug page (not debug_toolbar, just the page with list of installed apps, environment variables, stack trace, ...)

In my middleware, I have some cases (specific URLs, specific users, ...) where I want to remove this data and just return the raw response.
How should I do that?

currently my best idea is to just:

```
response.data = {}
return response
```

But I'm not sure if it's the proper way to do that, whether it covers all cases and so on. I just want to use a middleware to control in some cases and avoid the DEBUG mode for them.

Comment: Not sure if this will help but have you looked at the custom error reports section of [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/error-reporting/). Also, take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#exception-middleware) as well.

Comment: Can you please detail your use case and what you mean by "the raw response"? The debug page is rendered when an uncaught exception is raised. Why don't you want to see the details about this error and what do you want to see instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use exception middleware. [See Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) for more info.

Here is a sample implementation of the exception middleware:

```
class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        # if DEBUG is False we do not need this middleware
        if not settings.DEBUG:
            raise MiddlewareNotUsed
        self.get_response = get_response


    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)
    
    
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if request.user.is_authenticated: #any custom logic based on request and/or exception
            #returning None kicks in default exception handling 
            #i.e. it will show full debug info page if settings.DEBUG is True
            return None 
        
        else:
            #returning HttpResponse will force applying template response and response 
            #middleware and the resulting response will be returned to the browser
            return HttpResponse('Something went wrong')
```

Since Django 3.1 you may also use a custom error reporter class by defining the [DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#default-exception-reporter) setting. The custom error reporter class needs to inherit from [django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter) and you may override [get_traceback_data()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter.get_traceback_data) to implement custom logic. [See Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/error-reporting/#custom-error-reports) for more info.

Comment: Note that this solution does NOT catch exceptions thrown by other middlewares (whether below or above)